# Core Data Relationship

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

Searched a lot but could not fine a better solution, I m new to CoreData,
 I have a list of tables, each table has some chairs with people sitting on it. I have to save the name of person and their dress color only, if any person has a dress color of white I have to save his further information like Father's name, Address etc. I want to do it with CoreData but could not find a solution. Please Suggest a solution or tutorial.
Actually Each table will have people sitting on it, so it will be one to many relationship, while some table my not have any white dressed people, while some have more that one or two people sitting with white dress while other having not white dress, I m confused that how can save value only white dressed people and then to relate it with chairs and then Tables,

Comment: check this :http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Core_Data_Tutorial

Comment: This is basic tutorial with save and fetch result, It has not any relationship in it :(

Comment: Could you explain better your problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model should not care about the dress color. Just create a person entity which saves the dress color and has all the other attributes you need. Mark all the values that are only saved for people in white as optional in the core data inspector.

[image]

If you create a person that does not have a white dress, don't fill out the other values.

You can't specify "if person wears a white dress" in the data model. That part goes into the implementation, your actual code. If a person wears white fill in the information, if not then don't collect that information.

If you invite the whole world to your events you could consider adding two different entities `PersonWithOutWhiteDress` and `PersonWithWhiteDress`, but until you see actual performance issues I would stick with the single entity `Person`. Don't overcomplicate your data model if you don't have to.

And regarding relationships between entities: It does not matter how many relationships you save. Read the to-many and to-one as a limit of what you **can** save.
If you have a to-one relationship it can hold either 0 or 1 object. If you have a to-many relationship it can hold 0, 1 or many objects. (I have ignored min and max relationship limits you can specify in the data model)

If it should be possible to have a relationship to more than one object you want to create a to-many relationship. Even if you just save one relationship. In my proposed data model, if you have an empty table `persons` will contain 0 instances of `Person`. But the relationship is still to-many.